# How to use jspdf-autotable for pivot tables?

Tags: html-table, export, pivot-table, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I need to export a pivot table to PDF with multiple rows at header. The problem is that it always prints with one header, when actually I need more.

There is a image with the current table [pivot table to export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2CXK.jpg). Now the PDF exported looks like this [pdf exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyaB9.jpg).

You can see it's not consistent with the original, this my code so far:

```js
function ExportPdf()
   {    
     var pdfsize = 'a0';
     var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', pdfsize);

     var res = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementsByClassName("pvtTable")[0]);
     console.log(res.columns);
     console.log(res.data);
     pdf.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
     //pdf.autoTable({
    startY: 60,
    tableWidth: 'auto',
    columnWidth: 'auto',
    styles: {
      overflow: 'linebreak'
    }
     });

     pdf.save(pdfsize + ".pdf");

   }
```

The problem as I see it is autotable considers first row correctly, but not the rest of them. It is not considering the grouping that pivot makes. Can someone please resolve this.

Comment: Support for multiple headers rows, rowspans and colspans coming in v3 of the plugin. Until then this is quite cumbersome to sort out. It should be possible though with the hooks.

Comment: Is there an example of using hooks???

Comment: Yes, check the examples/exampes.js folder in the repo.